# How to tell if fish is subjected to Ciguatera?

Tags: fish

Is there any way to tell if fish is infected/subjected to ciguatera.

I understand that if you ingest fish that is infected with ciguatera you run the risk of becoming violently ill, and that subsequent ingestions will make you even more ill.  Therefore is there any way to tell if a fish has ciguatera?

I ask as I know not to eat certain fishes that I have caught in the tropics, but still do not know enough about the subject.

Comment: I'm removing the link because the link is to your own site, and the content on that page appears to be plagiarized, and the question is clear enough to stand on its own, without a link to more information.

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this, but if you would like to discuss whether it's okay to link to plagiarized content on your own ad/donation-supported site, please take it to [meta]. (Hint: it's not okay, and all you're going to get is a longer explanation of why not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a lab to test the fish.  Most outbreaks go unreported, or are spread too far apart. If it's local they would quit selling the fish for a week or two at a local market. That does not stop them from being shipped to a different location in 3rd world countries, or mixed in the fishing boats to be shipped wherever.

Comment: Thank you, however it is not just 3rd world countries, think of all the dolphin that goes into tuna cans.

Comment: Removed some comments about editing practices. If you would like to suggest an improvement, feel free to do so, or to suggest an edit directly. If you have questions about editing practices, take it to [meta].